# Can not insert data here and also can not delet the check constraint of this table

Tags: mysql

I copy and paste this from a mysql examples query page but like that tittle say, i can't insert data or delete the check constraint of this table creaded query. So please i need an explanation of those 2 things, the insert data and the drop check constrait of this table, thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS job_history ( 
EMPLOYEE_ID decimal(6,0) NOT NULL, 
START_DATE date NOT NULL, 
END_DATE date NOT NULL
CHECK (END_DATE LIKE '--/--/----'), 
JOB_ID varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
DEPARTMENT_ID decimal(4,0) NOT NULL 
);
```

Comment: Every index or constraint has a name; you need the name to remove it. if you don't provide one MySQL makes one up for you. Easiest way to see it is do `show create table job_history`

Comment: ok thanks now i need to know if i can insert data in this table.

Comment: Are you trying to enforce a non-standard date format on your `END_DATE` column? MySQL won't do that. Date format is always YYYY-MM-DD. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: i saw it here https://www.w3resource.com/mysql-exercises/create-table-exercises/create-table-exercise-7.php 

I belive its possible or isn't it?

Comment: Well, I would be pretty doubtful about that tutorial because it tells you to create the table in MySQL 5.6, but MySQL 5.6 didn't support CHECK constraints at all. That feature was first implemented in 8.0.16.

Comment: Also, the tutorial shows a CHECK constraint that limits a country_name column to three specific values. It has nothing to do with a date column.

Comment: i have the 8.0.31 version of mysql and i can insert digit in the region_id

Comment: @BillKarwin older versions of mysql, back through at least 5.5 if not earlier, would accept a CHECK constraint for compatibility purposes but just ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every index or constraint has a name; you need the name to remove it.  If you don't provide one MySQL makes one up for you. Easiest way to see it is do:

```
show create table job_history
```

You will see the constraint is named something like job_history_chk_1.  Remove it with:

```
alter table job_history drop constraint job_history_chk_1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t1JzVLHx)

The constraint you have makes no sense; it says that END_DATE, when cast to a string, must match the pattern `--/--/----`.  Since `-` and `/` are not like-operator metacharacters, that means it must be the exact string `--/--/----`.  And a date type column will never be that.  Whatever you were trying to do with that constraint needs to be done some completely different way, if indeed it is possible at all.